# No consigo que hacer un COPY en redshift que acepte milisegundos

Tags: sql, aws, redshift

Estoy intentando realizar un COPY en redshift, el problema es que al ver la tabla 'stl_load_errors', me aparece lo siguiente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta columna tendría que ser un TIMESTAMP, pero al introducir los milisegundos que vienen en el fichero me da error. Alguién puede ayudarme para añadir el formato correcto?

He probado en el copy con las siguientes formas y no han funcionado..

```
timeformat AS 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MI.SS.OF'
dateformat AS 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MI.SS.OF'

timeformat AS 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MI.SS.[.ffffff]'
dateformat AS 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MI.SS.[.ffffff]'

timeformat AS 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MI.SS'
dateformat AS 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MI.SS'

timeformat 'auto'
dateformat 'auto'
```

Comment: El [ejemplo](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#r_COPY_command_examples-load-a-time-datestamp) en la documentación usa `timeformat 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'`. Sin `AS`

Answer (score 0):

Bien, para solucionarlo hay que quitar el 'AS', tal y como dice @alfabravo, pero también hay que utilizar este format para los microsegundos

```
timeformat 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MI.SS.US'
dateformat 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MI.SS.US'
```

Dejo aquí la tabla de formateos de fechas de redshift por si alguién lo necesita.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FORMAT_strings.html